# Java Client API - Get all bins in a single call?

Tags: java, aerospike

Instead of making **multiple calls** to aerospike for **each ldt bin**, is there any way to make just one call and retrieve all the bins ?

eg.

Suppose a Record contains :

1. bin1
2. bin2
3. bin3
4. largelistBin1
5. largeListBin2
6. largeMapBin1
7. largeMapBin2

Now to retrieve all of the data I am making these calls :

```
 - client.get(myPolicy, key)
 - client.getLargeMap(myPolicy, key, largeMapBin1, null)
   - myLargeMap1.scan()
 - client.getLargeMap(myPolicy, key, largeMapBin2, null)
   - myLargeMap2.scan()
 - client.getLargeList(myPolicy, key, largeListBin1, null)
   - myLargeList1.scan()
 - client.getLargeList(myPolicy, key, largelistBin2, null)
   - myLargeList2.scan()
```

Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no better way at this point. Each ldt bin has to be retrieved separately.